# Send answer to native application from onMessage() event listener

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I need to establish a bidirectional communication between firefox webextension and native application. I need to send data back to the native application only if I received specific event. I've read that it is possible to establish bidirectional communication between content script and background script using sendResponse() or Window.postMessage function, but nothing is mentioned regarding background script and native application. So, being more specific here is some code snippet:

```
var nativeAppPort = browser.runtime.connectNative("nativeApp");
nativeAppPort.onMessage.addListener((response) => {
 if (response.respType == "response_event_type") {
  nativeAppPort.postMessage(message); //<-----IS IT OK TO DO SO?
 }
}
```

Is it OK to postMessage() inside event listener? Is there any other approach? Thank you!

Comment: And what's wrong with using postMessage inside event listener? The question is unclear.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @wOxxOm. I asked it because it is not mentioned about it in the documentation regarding native messaging. It is stated that it is OK for communication between content script and background script, with the exeption that the next event(or answer) will be handled after the previous event is finished processing. If that is the same case for native messaging - then the answer is obvious.

Comment: No, I don't see how that can be a problem since JS environment is always single-threaded.